# Usage of "aber", "jedoch" and "allerdings"

Tags: difference, usage, particle

What is the difference between *allerdings*, *aber* and *jedoch*? I looked them up in the dictionary and all three mean '*but*'.
Could anyone tell me how they're used in a sentence?

Answer (score 8):

All three have their own peculiarity. The following is about the usage as *[adversative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adversative) conjunction*. Note that they all somehow have a stressing effect since they introduce something like a oppositional causality.

> 1. Er arbeitet 50 Stunden die Woche, **aber** er ist immer gut drauf.
> 2. Er arbeitet 50 Stunden die Woche, **jedoch** ist er immer gut drauf.
> 3. Er arbeitet 50 Stunden die Woche, **allerdings** ist er immer gut drauf.

1. Let's take this as a rather neutral case
2. then *jedoch* is even more sober, professional, unemotional, standard ...
3. whereas *allerdings* itself has something brightly, confirmative, positive in it.

Change the sentence and it's context, these connotations might blur away. It's just an attempt of characterization of slightly different connotations and it's very hard to exclude tone and context and just focus the conjunction itself.

Comment: Wann kann man "jenoch" oder "jedoch" benutzen ?

Comment: @mina see my revised answer. There is no `jenoch`, only `dennoch` which emphasizes even more what follows.

Answer (score 6):

Kein Unterschied hier:

> Ich bin kein Professor für Philosophie, habe aber 30 Semester Philosophie studiert.
>
> Ich bin kein Professor für Philosophie, habe jedoch 30 Semester Philosophie studiert.
>
> Ich bin kein Professor für Philosophie, habe allerdings 30 Semester Philosophie studiert.

Nur *allerdings* möglich:

> Q: "Kennen Sie sich etwa mit Nietzsche aus?"
>
> A: "Allerdings!"

Answer (score 4):

The difference is function. All 3 can be a commentating adverb. This is the use that was examplified in the other answer.

- Ich habe Hunger, ich will *aber/jedoch/allerdings* nicht essen.

Sentences like these will be translated using the English *but*. However, *but* is a conjunction so functionally it is NOT a translation. It only translates the idea. Closer translations when it comes to function would be *however* or *though*

- I am hungry. [However], I don't want to eat [though].

*Aber* can also be a conjunction.

- Ich habe Hunger, aber ich will nichts essen.

*Jedoch* as well... but it is not that common and you'd need to make a pause to make it clear.

- Ich habe Hunger. Jedoch [pause] Ich will nichts essen.

*Allerdings* can't do that. So *allerdings* will always count as one position of the sentence. Also, as pointed out in the other answer it can also have an affirmative meaning and that is not the case for "jedoch" and "aber".
So... all 3 words can mean *but* but *but* is neither the only nor the best translation for *jedoch* and *allerdings*.

Comment: Your pause in the last sentence just hides the wrong word order.  Correct is: *Ich habe Hunger, jedoch will ich nichts essen.*

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Oder `Ich habe Hunger, (ich) will jedoch nichts essen.`

Comment: Wieso nicht: `Ich habe Hunger, will allerdings nichts essen.`

Comment: @Carsten Schultz... the fat Duden Grammatik lists this position 0 "jedoch" as a conjunction if I recall correctly (I've seen it about a month ago). So, in my opinion the word order is not wrong... it is just rare.

Comment: @user unknown: ... skipping the "ich" is of course an option but "ich" or no "ich" doesn't change the fact that we're dealing with commentating adverbs in all cases where the word is NOT in position 0

Comment: Not the most trustworthy link on earth maybe but by internet grammar standards probably the most comprehensive out there:  http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Konjunktion/Bedeutung/adversativ.html   "jedoch" feels a lot like "allein" to me and with the "allein" there is no doubt that the required pause is not hiding a wrong sentence structure

Comment: Ok, @Emanuel, I have no theoretical knowledge of grammar. But if you also think that “..., jedoch will ich nichts essen” is more common and that “..., jedoch ich will nichts essen” requires a pause to sound good, then we have hardly a substantive disagreement anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using user_unknowns examples.

> Ich bin kein Professor für Philosophie, habe **aber** 30 Semester
>   Philosophie studiert.

--> juxtaposition

I'm no expert, **but** still have learned a lot.

> Ich bin kein Professor für Philosophie, habe **jedoch** 30 Semester
>   Philosophie studiert.

Change in focus. But no direct juxtaposition.

--> I'm no expert, **however** I have learned a lot. (and still might be able to help you.)

> Ich bin kein Professor für Philosophie, habe **allerdings** 30 Semester
>   Philosophie studiert.

--> I'm no expert, **though** I have learned a lot. > Better as Though I have learned a lot, I'm no expert.

--> This means more. Even though I have learned a lot, I'm still no expert. I have got more to learn.

A clarification. I know a lot already, but still need to learn more.

Nur allerdings möglich: (**Nope**)

> Q: "Kennen Sie sich etwa mit Nietzsche aus?"
>
> A: "**Allerdings**!" OR "Nein, **jedoch** kenne ich mich mit Kant aus." OR **Aber** ich bitte sie, wer kennt Nietzsche nicht?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there are two common uses of "allerdings"

1) It can be used in as a pointed **confirmatory exclamation** similar to the use of "of course" "indeed" or "certainly" in English. According to native German speakers I have conversed with, "allerdings" is employed most frequentely, though not exclusively, to convey a negative sentiment.

> “Das ist ein Problem.”
>   “So ein Kackwetter.”
>   “Also, das klingt aber sehr weit hergeholt.”
>   “Puh...das war knapp.”
>   “Ich hätte wahrscheinlich fragen sollen, bevor ich dein Bier nehme.”
>
> "That is a problem.”
>   “What crappy weather.”
>   “Well, that sounds far fetched.”
>   “Phew… that was close.”
>   “I guess I should have asked, before taking your beer.”

To all that people answer “Allerdings” all the time. Those are allerdings-moments.

(source: https://yourdailygerman.wordpress.com/2014/03/31/allerdings-meaning)

2) It can also be used to **emphasize a contrast, counterpoint or an exception to a statement** that has been made. In other words, it can be used to qualify a statement or supposition (in German: Eine Aussage einschränken).  In this sense it could be translated as "however" "although" "though" "admittedly" "in any case" "albeit" in English

> Im Berichtsjahr verringerte sich die Anzahl der Schadenfälle um 18,3 Prozent bei allerdings leicht erhöhtem Aufwand pro Schadenfall.*

oder

> Die SMC war bis 1990 rentabel, allerdings auf einem niedrigen, rückläufigen Niveau.*

source linguee.de