# German equivalent of "..., though"

Tags: translation, word-choice, single-word-request, colloquial

For example, how would you say "The weather is nice, though".

This is used in the sense of continuing someone else's thought, usually with a contrasting sentiment. For example, if two friends go to a park to watch a football game, only to find out when they arrive that it has been cancelled, their conversation might go like this:

> Person 1: "I can't believe I wasted an hour travelling out here."
>     Person 2: "Weather is nice though"

What is the German equivalent of that trailing "though"?

Comment: My suggestion (which can and will surely be improved): doch das Wetter ist gut/allerdings ist das Wetter gut.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of "aber", "jedoch" and "allerdings"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8134/usage-of-aber-jedoch-and-allerdings)

Answer (score 11):

You can find possible translations for *though* in dictionaries, for example try [Pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=though&l=deen&in=&lf=de).

I recommend that dictionary for putting words into categories, so you can find out to which definition the translations fit. (In your case you're looking for the adverb, not the conjunction.)

Including their example sentences, you'll find those translations: *dennoch*, *immerhin*, *trotz allem*, *allerdings*

There are certainly more possibilities and it always depends on context. In your sentence *immerhin* is quite a good choice:

> Immerhin ist das Wetter gut.

To provide you an alternative, you could use *zumindest*, too.

> Zumindest ist das Wetter gut.

I can hardly give you any advice on how to figure out which word is appropriate in each context. Could you give me any hints on when to use *though* over *nevertheless*, for instance? That is, you need to get some language feel. I know this is disappointing for now.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at, is that the use of "though" is not grammatically correct in the english sentence - it should be "although the weather is nice", but no-one would actually say that. So I wondered if germans had an equivalent, a way to tag a sentence as implicitly meaning "I agree, but..." in a way that is not technically correct.

Comment: @Benubird I feel I misinterpreted your question, as I wasn't aware of this usage of "though". So, if I now get you right, the proper way would be like "(Und das) obwohl das Wetter doch gut ist" or "Dabei ist das Wetter doch gut". I'm not sure if German has a direct equivalent here.

Comment: I'd put "allerdings" and "dennoch" into the focus, as "zumindest" and "trotz allem" do imply more than just contrast. (I am referring to the examples)

Answer (score 8):

> Aber wenigstens ist das Wetter ganz gut.

Comment: please add some explanation and not just a "stupid translation". no offense, but we are here to help people learn german and not to provide a "translation service". You can read some more in [answer] and hte [help/on-topic] ... Either way: Welcome to [german.se]

Comment: @Vogel612 Aber wenigstens ist der Beispielsatz korrekt. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The German equivalent for "though" at the end of a sentence is mostly allerdings.

Two heart attacks in a year. It hasn't stopped him smoking, though.
Zwei Herzinfarkte in einem Jahr. Mit dem Rauchen hat er allerdings nicht aufgehört.
Here would fit aber, jedoch, trotzdem, freilich as well.

In other cases, as in your example, you can use wenigstens, zumindest, aber.

Answer (score 3):

I feel that

> Aber das Wetter ist gut.

comes near. It may be less specific, but since the construction involves no inversion, it better preserves the laconic nature of the comment.

Answer (score 2):

> "Ich kann's nicht glauben, dass wir extra umsonst hierher gefahren sind!"
>   "Aber wenigstens ist das Wetter schön!"

This is how I would say it. The translation is simple.

To stronger the contrasting sentiment I maybe would:

- emphasize strongly the first word "aber"
- add some mimics. I definitely would grin at the end of the sentence =)

Mimics and emotions are important often. That's the reason people invented them for Internet chats o_O. Sometimes I think it's a shame they don't exist in books, but maybe that leaves more space for fantasy, ... though... ;)

PS:
"Though" I would translate using:
"Aber wenigstens", "Trotzdem"

Answer (score 2):

All the answers here are fine, but I am afraid there is no true equivalent to the english swiss-army-knife word "though". A feature I often miss in German.

But there *is* another swiss-army-knife word in German, which is absent in English and this is the word ***ja***. You find it in many places and the literal translation "yes" doesn't get you anywhere.

Luckily in this case the two knives are pretty compatible and a  good translation of your sentence which preserves much of the "though" feel is

> Das Wetter ist ja schön

It is not 100% equivalent, but neither are *allerdings* or *wenigstens*. *Immerhin* is good in this context, though (sic!) not a general replacement for *though*

And you would most likely not use it with *aber*.

Using *ja* correctly is not easy, but it is fun.

Answer (score 0):

> Person 2: "Weather is nice **though**"

**Immerhin** ist das Wetter schön.

**Jedenfalls**, das Wetter ist schön.

**Zumindest** das Wetter ist schön.

**Auf jeden Fall** ist das Wetter schön.

**Trotz allem** das Wetter ist schön.

Das Wetter ist gut immerhin. (not really correct grammar, though)

Answer (score 0):

If you translate "though," in the sense of "however," the word I would use is aber.

Das Wetter ist ABER gut.